# D3 Group on nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working with data like this:

```
[{key:"1", tags:[{name:"user1"}, {name:"bot2"}]},
 {key:"2", tags:[{name:"user3"}, {name:"bot4"}]},
 {key:"3", tags:[{name:"user5"}, {name:"user1"}]}]
```

I have javascript code that will group on tag name, listing all unique values and removing duplicates, and give me this:

`["user1","bot2","user3","bot4","user5"]`

I would like to replace that using the D3 library.

I looked for docs, but the references on different versions are mixing me up.

Comment: So is your question how to replace the data attached to the group?

Comment: How to group from the existing data. If I was dealing with flat data, like the key property, I would do something like this: Array.from(group(data, d => d.key)).keys()) . . . . I don't know how to group when the field is an array of objects.

Comment: why is "bot1" not supposed to be in the result array?

Comment: do you want to group your data by key or by tags name?

Comment: @ee2Dev, you're right, I wanted to type user1, showing that it had to remove duplicates

Comment: @cal_br_mar tag names please

Answer (score 0):

You don't need d3.js for your data wrangling. You can use plain javascript.
Here is one way to do it:

```js
    const intialData = [{key:"1", tags:[{name:"user1"}, {name:"bot2"}]},
     {key:"2", tags:[{name:"user3"}, {name:"bot4"}]},
     {key:"3", tags:[{name:"user5"}, {name:"bot1"}]}];
    
    const d1 = intialData.map((ele) => ele.tags);
    log("d1", d1);
    
    let d2 = [];
    d1.forEach((ele) => {
      ele.forEach((ele) => { d2.push(ele.name);});
    });
    log("d2", d2);
    
    const d3 = new Set(d2);
    log("d3", d3);;
    
    const d4 = Array.from(d3);
    log("d4", d4);
    function log(str, obj) { console.log(str+ ":"); console.log(obj);}
```

Comment: I have a similar approach now. What I did was create an object, and just loop through and add as keys, then run Object.keys() on it.

If I can get rid of that code, I can remove a helper I made, and just call d3 in the top level code.

Comment: It would be good to post your answer or accept my answer so viewers have one solution

Comment: But my answer doesn't use D3.